# Supply topology for microcontroller and ADC/sensor with noisy input/outputs

Tags: adc, switch-mode-power-supply, noise, voltage-reference

I am experimenting with a microcontroller project with a very wide-ranging, noisy DC input voltage at VCC. The controller processes a sensor input to the ADC and outputs a pulsed signal on all pins of a separate port. I need some advice on the best way to configure the system and microcontroller (ATmega168) supply (VCC/AVCC/AREF) to make the ADC and sensor as immune to all of the switching noise as possible.  I’ve drawn up 3 possibilities of the top of my head below, but not sure which, if any, is optimal for separating digital and analog noise as much as possible:

Possibility 1:
[image]

Possibility 2:
[image]

Possibility 3:
[image]

Currently I’m testing with both Vcc and AVcc powered from a linear bench supply (output 5.3V), and using a TL431 as 5V reference at Aref (similar to possibility 3).  A potentiometer is standing in for the sensor. Despite large capacitors between +5.3V and COM (4400uF total), the multiplexing currently causes a lot of noise on the reference output.  Below is a scope screenshot of the reference output, and this is without the switcher:

[image]

What is the best basic topology to supply this circuit? Any comments, recommendations or better ideas than any of these would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your grounding look like?

Comment: What SNR or Effective Number Of Bits do you need? Is the ADC differential input? How big a capacitor on VREF pin? Is your GROUND a plane? or daisychain? or what?

Comment: @abe So far, testing is being done on a breadboard, so not great. I am using separate ground strips for the multiplexing and analog sides, though, in as much of a star configuration as possible, so the currents have minimal overlap.

Comment: @analog: ADC is the on-board 10 bit, single-ended, Vref has 100nF currently, I need all the bits so it's pretty tight, the LSB does fluctuate +-1 bit currently with the setup as described depending on the current difference between displays, but if current difference between displays isn't too large (similar segment number) then it stays surprisingly stable

Comment: If you need 10-bit accuracy, you probably can't use the onboard ADC: the datasheet claims a typical error of 4.5 LSB.

Comment: I don't think any microcontroller can directly drive 100 - 450 mA pulses from its GPIO pins - you will need a separate driver circuiit to feed the displays.

Comment: @PeterBennett: You definitely cannot, I'm using a ULN2003A transistor array for selection and 8 PNP transistors for driving individual LEDs

Comment: @Abe: I'll have to spend some time reading that datasheet section again, didn't realize it was quite THAT bad, I could live with +/-1 LSB and was hoping just to keep it stable (not jumpy) for now. Was planning on asking about/discussing the ADC accuracy in another post, as not to detract too much from the responses to the power issue

Comment: Is your sensor ratiometric (i.e. is the output linear with the supply voltage)? If so, you want to power it off of AREF, otherwise AVCC.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "linear with the supply voltage", the sensor output is linear with respect to what it's measuring though. You mean power the sensor from the same source as is powering Aref or AVcc, correct?

Comment: As an example of a ratiometric sensor, consider measuring resistance with a voltage divider: the voltage output will depend on the resistance of the sensor, but will also (for example) double if the supply voltage doubles. Link the datasheet for your sensor and I'll be able to explain better. (Also, that is indeed what I meant about powering the sensor.)

Comment: @Abe, so if I've got a post-switcher LDO powering the sensor and AVcc, would you recommend using the same LDO output as Aref for the ADC? Or would you recommend using a separate voltage reference?

Comment: I can't answer that without knowing more about the sensor. If the sensor output is absolute, having a separate reference for AREF can improve accuracy. If it's ratiometric, you want AREF to be connected to the sensor's power supply.

Answer (score 1):

Only answering part of your question:

Since the worst noisemaker here is the multiplexed LED display, you have several options:

1- Use a LCD instead, with a constant-current LED backlight.

2- Keep the high LED currents inside a tight loop close to the 7-seg modules. To do this you would put the 7seg drivers close to the display, route the return currents in traces (don't let them into your ground plane), and use local decoupling to close the loop, like several hundreds µF with lowish ESR like 0.1R (Panasonic FC for example). Then, power the whole display from the switching regulator, not from your clean 5V. You could also add a cheap slow LDO or a RC filter to smooth the current drawn from the supply.

Also you won't get 1LSB accuracy from the micro's ADC, the TL431 is only accurate to 1% too, so this feels like you need to clearly specify what kind of accuracy you require...

Comment: Great, thank you for the input ... I like your second idea, along with what I was originally thinking, so you would recommend the LED driver power come directly from the switching regulator, isolating it from clean power. Would you recommend the uC Vcc then be powered by a post-switcher LDO, and the AVcc as well? Should the reference input then also come from the same regulator, or should I use a separate reference?  W/ regard to the accuracy, it justifiably crept into the answers to this question, but I am actually saving it for another post, as I felt it might detract from the power issue

Comment: If this is a personal project and you're not going to build 10k boards then parts cost isn't that relevant. For example a LDO will cost 50c, so don't spend an hour wondering whether you'll put one or two on your board ;) likewise if you need accuracy, spend a few bucks on an ADC with more bits, it'll save you time...

Comment: Right, cost of an extra regulator or reference isn't the concern at the moment, it's really just getting the overall supply topology as good as I can get it to keep the switching noise under control and allow for the best operation of the ADC, whether I use the on-board ADC or an external one. So to bug you one more time about this ;), we've got the LED drivers powered by a switcher and the sensor and ADC powered by an LDO, should the uC Vcc be powered by the LDO also?(since it's switching the LED drivers) And would you recommend using a separate reference or is the LDO good enough for ADCref?

Comment: Well a "reference" and a "regulator" are the more or less the same, except the "reference" will be designed for higher accuracy, lower tempco, etc, and the "regulator" is designed for higher current (and no-one cares if it drifts by 1% versus temp). What you don't want to do is draw a varying current from your reference, because it does have a transient response, so it will take some time to settle if the output current varies.

Comment: So if you want good accuracy, a reference chip (or TL431, whatever gives you the accuracy you need) should only power the ARef pin, and not other stuff that draws pulsed current. This is why using the micro's +5V as reference isn't accurate, as the +5V will vary a bit with CPU load, as the cpu's current demands vary, same if it drives loads from its outputs etc... Now I don't what rejection the micro's AVCC pin has, you can put a RC or RLC filter with a ferrite bead and a MLCC like 10µF on AVCC pin, that should filter out any HF noise.

Comment: As for having one LDO for the micro VCC and one for the sensor, this depends on the sensor's power supply rejection, as I said when in doubt spend the extra 50 cents...